# React Native, refresh activity when user resumes app after a while?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Suppose you have a news app like Yahoo.

When a user runs your app and move out of your app (without quitting the app).

After a while (like an hour) he comes back, and you want to refresh the page (if he's seeing the front Yahoo page, it may have new news to show)

Is this a thing that I don't need to worry about because android actually disposes the long lived activity?

Or is this a thing that I have to implement it myself?

If I have to do it myself, should I implement this with saving 'exit time' and  comparing it with 'resume time' and so forth or are there android/ios support or github library?

Comment: You can use AppState API - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea about Android life cycle and activity by browsing this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

If you create an application using react-native and deploy it to both Android and IOS, you need to use a compatible react-native module for that.

If you only consider an android application. You can override `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods to do what u want in certain states.

eg: If u want to reload new content when reopening the application, u need to override that refresh criterion in an overridden `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to update the content after however long, assuming that your data is coming from a remote source that you are loading within your React Native application - you can hit one of the React Native JS lifecycle events.

For example, you can use `componentDidMount()`:

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions. If you do that, don’t forget to unsubscribe in `componentWillUnmount()`.

If youre wanting to create a custom React Native Module, then you'll need to create an Android Service - but assuming you have an API endpoint for your data and the data will only be refreshed when the user is interacting with the app - I don't see why you'd need a custom module. It's all built in already.

Answer (score 0):

You should use facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate to check when the app becomes `active`, and then you do stuff.